# Magento: Incorrect template design for login and register page due to Persistent Shopping Cart

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and my login and register page design has problem. It is not taking the template path from my custom theme. Instead, it is taking the template path from base persistent folder.

For example, the login template path is taken from
**frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml** instead of
**frontend/default/MY_THEME/template/customer/form/login.phtml**

It’s strange how this persistent folder come into action.

**I try below things also**

**1) Copy the persistent folder from design base directory to your custom theme directory. And then modify the design on the files you copied.**

**2)Disable the persistent shopping cart feature. You can do this from :
System -> Configuration -> CUSTOMERS -> Persistent Shopping Cart -> General Options -> Enable Persistence = No**

**3)directly disable the module by editing the file: app/etc/modules/Mage_Persistent.xml by setting active = false.**

Also did Refresh my Magento cache and also browser cache!

Is there any other solution or suggestion that i have to applied other then this?

Waiting for your kind response.

Comment: Have you tried copying the phtml file from `frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml` to `frontend/base/default/MY_THEME/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml`?

Comment: hello i already mention in my question the things i have already try. so i already try this things but not working any other suggestion

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see that you had done that specifically. If you have copied the login.phtml into your theme and it's still not displaying any changes, you might have to check that the permissions on the login.phtml file in your theme are correct

Comment: yes it's 644 i try to set 777 but still not display.

Comment: yes i do refresh cache too @Brats

Answer (score 3):

1. Copy **login.phtml** from **frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/** to **frontend/default/MY_THEME/template/persistent/customer/form/** (You have already done this)
2. **Clear the Magento CACHE.** Even your browser cache.

If still doesn't shows up, then check the folder path. **If you have placed it correctly**, it **should show** the Theme Template path in the hints. There is no bug in Magento which causes this kinda problem.
Make sure the Theme where you have copied the persistent login.phtml is the Theme that you are using in design settings.

Comment: I agree, you need to change theme first then clear your cache and if files are placed in frontend/default/MY_THEME/template/persistent/customer/form/  they will be definitely picked by Magento..

Answer (score 0):

Copy your template from frontend/default/MY_THEME/template/customer/form/login.phtml to frontend/default/MY_THEME/template/persistent/customer/form/Login.phtml, then refresh your Cache. Now the changes you did to the Login.phtml should be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a module can overwrite the template used for the login form. And maybe you are missing the template files. You should check for layout xml handles like:

```
<customer_account_login>
   <reference name="customer_form_login">
   <action method="setTemplate"><template>template/name.phtml</template></action>
   </reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

Another thing you should check is if the block used for the login is the core one because again a template override may happen from a module.